# Import public-only elliptic curve into Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to import the public portion of an elliptic curve into Azure Key Vault. The request works successfully when I include the private and public portions (i.e., the D, X, and Y fields) however if I only submit the public portions (i.e., the X, and Y fields) I receive error "EC key is not valid - cannot instantiate crypto service."

Below are two requests submitting the same key to Azure Key Vault under two different identifiers; the first request includes the private key information (and is successful) and the second is the public key information only and returns the described error.

First example w/ private info:

```
PUT https://XXX.vault.azure.net/keys/f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f0?api-version=7.4 HTTP/1.1
Host: XXX.vault.azure.net
Authorization: Bearer XXX
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 274

{"kid":"f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f0","key":{"kid":"f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f0","kty":"EC","crv":"P-256","d":"Wjdwwdd2dnf9QT6KqXsexBSs0DEbnKsfj0vW3fNkvJo","x":"U4h1986Oy6ARYQxIBU3JRGIuHA_GhWcPT1zwYAaG9Rg","y":"8_-7MQY-fiY2UvBcgnNtSqrs1AeoNxXvo-21mn8dKJs"}}
```

Second example w/o private info:

```
PUT https://XXX.vault.azure.net/keys/f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f9?api-version=7.4 HTTP/1.1
Host: XXX.vault.azure.net
Authorization: Bearer XXX
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 224

{"kid":"f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f9","key":{"kid":"f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f9","kty":"EC","crv":"P-256","x":"U4h1986Oy6ARYQxIBU3JRGIuHA_GhWcPT1zwYAaG9Rg","y":"8_-7MQY-fiY2UvBcgnNtSqrs1AeoNxXvo-21mn8dKJs"}}
```

Response from second request:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 102
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
Date: Thu, 27 Jul 2023 13:34:44 GMT

{"error":{"code":"BadParameter","message":"EC key is not valid - cannot instantiate crypto service."}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure Key Vault requires the **private key information (D field)** in
> order to import an elliptic curve key. Without the private key
> information, the request will fail with error.

When I tried to import the **public portion** of an elliptic curve into Azure Key Vault without private key, I got **same error** as below:

```http
PUT https://sri-kv.vault.azure.net//keys/f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f0?api-version=7.4
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "kid":"f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f0",
  "key": {
    "kty": "EC",
    "crv" : "P-256",
    "x": "U4h1986Oy6ARYQxIBU3JRGIuHA_GhWcPT1zwYAaG9Rg",
    "y": "8_-7MQY-fiY2UvBcgnNtSqrs1AeoNxXvo-21mn8dKJs"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you cannot import **public-only** elliptic curve into Azure
> Key Vault. To resolve the error, you must include **private key** in
> the request.

When I ran the request again by including **private key** in `d` parameter same as your first request, I got **response** successfully like below:

```http
PUT https://sri-kv.vault.azure.net//keys/f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f0?api-version=7.4
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json

{
 "kid":"f851dad4-3a02-4039-90fa-6aed47fa06f0",
  "key": {
    "kty": "EC",
    "crv" : "P-256",
    "d":"Wjdwwdd2dnf9QT6KqXsexBSs0DEbnKsfj0vW3fNkvJo",
    "x": "U4h1986Oy6ARYQxIBU3JRGIuHA_GhWcPT1zwYAaG9Rg",
    "y": "8_-7MQY-fiY2UvBcgnNtSqrs1AeoNxXvo-21mn8dKJs"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where key imported successfully in key vault:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Is it possible to just import a public P256K EC key by **Manoj Reddy-MSFT**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0a70d808-445e-4b25-9d0f-37009ade1b55/is-it-possible-to-just-import-a-public-p256k-ec-key?forum=AzureKeyVault)